# Storing the results of a macro into a table

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data-manipulation

I found a procedure in R that I want to iterate for different values.

The original procedure looks like this (runs completely in base R):

```
# A minimalistic Echo State Networks demo with Mackey-Glass (delay 17) data 
# in "plain" R.
# by Mantas Lukosevicius 2012-2018
# http://mantas.info

myfile <- read.table(url("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt"))

# load the data
trainLen = 2000
testLen = 2000
initLen = 100
data = as.matrix(myfile)

# plot some of it
while( dev.cur() != 1 ) dev.off() # close all previous plots
dev.new()
plot(data[1:1000],type='l')
title(main='A sample of data')

# generate the ESN reservoir
inSize = outSize = 1
resSize = 1000
a = 0.3 # leaking rate

set.seed(42)
Win = matrix(runif(resSize*(1+inSize),-0.5,0.5),resSize)
W = matrix(runif(resSize*resSize,-0.5,0.5),resSize)

# normalizing and setting spectral radius
cat('Computing spectral radius...')
rhoW = abs(eigen(W,only.values=TRUE)$values[1])
print('done.')
W = W * 1.25 / rhoW

# allocated memory for the design (collected states) matrix
X = matrix(0,1+inSize+resSize,trainLen-initLen)
# set the corresponding target matrix directly
Yt = matrix(data[(initLen+2):(trainLen+1)],1)

# run the reservoir with the data and collect X
x = rep(0,resSize)
for (t in 1:trainLen){
    u = data[t]
    x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
    if (t > initLen)
        X[,t-initLen] = rbind(1,u,x)
}

# train the output
reg = 1e-8  # regularization coefficient
X_T = t(X)
Wout = Yt %*% X_T %*% solve( X %*% X_T + reg*diag(1+inSize+resSize) )

# run the trained ESN in a generative mode. no need to initialize here, 
# because x is initialized with training data and we continue from there.
Y = matrix(0,outSize,testLen)
u = data[trainLen+1]
for (t in 1:testLen){
    x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
    y = Wout %*% rbind(1,u,x)
    Y[,t] = y
    # generative mode:
    u = y
    # this would be a predictive mode:
    #u = data[trainLen+t+1] 
}

# compute MSE for the first errorLen time steps
errorLen = 500
mse = ( sum( (data[(trainLen+2):(trainLen+errorLen+1)] - Y[1,1:errorLen])^2 )
    / errorLen )
print( paste( 'MSE = ', mse ) )

# plot some signals
dev.new() 
plot( data[(trainLen+1):(trainLen+testLen+1)], type='l', col='green' )
lines( c(Y), col='blue' )
title(main=expression(paste('Target and generated signals ', bold(y)(italic(n)), 
    ' starting at ', italic(n)==0 )))
legend('bottomleft',legend=c('Target signal', 'Free-running predicted signal'), 
    col=c('green','blue'), lty=1, bty='n' )

dev.new()
matplot( t(X[(1:20),(1:200)]), type='l' )
title(main=expression(paste('Some reservoir activations ', bold(x)(italic(n)))))

dev.new()
barplot( Wout )
title(main=expression(paste('Output weights ', bold(W)^{out})))
```

I want to run this procedure for different values of the parameters "resSize" and "a". Doing a bit of research and a lot of trial and error, I was able to figure out how to loop the above procedure for 3 different values of "resSize" and 3 different values of "a" - for a total of 9 values. See below:

```
myfile <- read.table(url("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt"))

# load the data
trainLen = 2000
testLen = 2000
initLen = 100
data = as.matrix(myfile)

# plot some of it
while( dev.cur() != 1 ) dev.off() # close all previous plots
dev.new()
plot(data[1:1000],type='l')
title(main='A sample of data')

# LOOP generate the ESN reservoir, different reservoir sizes and leakage rates
inSize = outSize = 1
for (resSize in c(100,500,1000)) {
    for (a in c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7))     {
    ### resSize = 1000
    ### a = 0.3 # leaking rate

    set.seed(42)
    Win = matrix(runif(resSize*(1+inSize),-0.5,0.5),resSize)
    W = matrix(runif(resSize*resSize,-0.5,0.5),resSize)

    # normalizing and setting spectral radius
    cat('Computing spectral radius...')
    rhoW = abs(eigen(W,only.values=TRUE)$values[1])
    print('done.')
    W = W * 1.25 / rhoW

    # allocated memory for the design (collected states) matrix
    X = matrix(0,1+inSize+resSize,trainLen-initLen)
    # set the corresponding target matrix directly
    Yt = matrix(data[(initLen+2):(trainLen+1)],1)

    # run the reservoir with the data and collect X
    x = rep(0,resSize)
      for (t in 1:trainLen){
      u = data[t]
      x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
      if (t > initLen)
          X[,t-initLen] = rbind(1,u,x)
      }

      # train the output
      reg = 1e-8  # regularization coefficient
      X_T = t(X)
      Wout = Yt %*% X_T %*% solve( X %*% X_T + reg*diag(1+inSize+resSize) )

      # run the trained ESN in a generative mode. no need to initialize here,
      # because x is initialized with training data and we continue from there.
      Y = matrix(0,outSize,testLen)
      u = data[trainLen+1]
      for (t in 1:testLen) {
      x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
      y = Wout %*% rbind(1,u,x)
      Y[,t] = y
      # generative mode:
      u = y
      # this would be a predictive mode:
      #u = data[trainLen+t+1]
      }

  # compute MSE for the first errorLen time steps
  errorLen = 500
  mse = ( sum( (data[(trainLen+2):(trainLen+errorLen+1)] - Y[1,1:errorLen])^2 )
/ errorLen )
  print( paste( 'Reservoir Size =',resSize))
  print( paste( 'Leakage Rate =',a))
  print( paste( 'MSE = ', mse ) )

  # plot some signals
  dev.new()
  plot( data[(trainLen+1):(trainLen+testLen+1)], type='l', col='green' )
  lines( c(Y), col='blue' )
  title(main=expression(paste('Target and generated signals ', bold(y)(italic(n)),
' starting at ', italic(n)==0 )))
  legend('bottomleft',legend=c('Target signal', 'Free-running predicted signal'),
col=c('green','blue'), lty=1, bty='n' )

  dev.new()
  matplot( t(X[(1:20),(1:200)]), type='l' )
  title(main=expression(paste('Some reservoir activations ', bold(x)(italic(n)))))

 dev.new()
 barplot( Wout )
 title(main=expression(paste('Output weights ', bold(W)^{out})))

  }
}
```

This outputs the 9 different results. I am trying to figure out how to make a table of these results (3 columns "Reservoir Size", "Leakage Rate" and "MSE"). Right now, I am copying and pasting the results from R into Microsoft Excel to do so.

Can someone please show me a simpler way to do this?

Thanks

UPDATE: answer provided by G Grothendieck, see below:

```
myfile <- read.table(url("https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt"))
mseDF <- NULL
# load the data
trainLen = 2000
testLen = 2000
initLen = 100
data = as.matrix(myfile)

# plot some of it
while( dev.cur() != 1 ) dev.off() # close all previous plots
dev.new()
plot(data[1:1000],type='l')
title(main='A sample of data')

# LOOP generate the ESN reservoir, different reservoir sizes and leakage rates
inSize = outSize = 1
for (resSize in c(100,500,1000)) {
    for (a in c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7))     {
    ### resSize = 1000
    ### a = 0.3 # leaking rate

    set.seed(42)
    Win = matrix(runif(resSize*(1+inSize),-0.5,0.5),resSize)
    W = matrix(runif(resSize*resSize,-0.5,0.5),resSize)

    # normalizing and setting spectral radius
    cat('Computing spectral radius...')
    rhoW = abs(eigen(W,only.values=TRUE)$values[1])
    print('done.')
    W = W * 1.25 / rhoW

    # allocated memory for the design (collected states) matrix
    X = matrix(0,1+inSize+resSize,trainLen-initLen)
    # set the corresponding target matrix directly
    Yt = matrix(data[(initLen+2):(trainLen+1)],1)

    # run the reservoir with the data and collect X
    x = rep(0,resSize)
      for (t in 1:trainLen){
      u = data[t]
      x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
      if (t > initLen)
          X[,t-initLen] = rbind(1,u,x)
      }

      # train the output
      reg = 1e-8  # regularization coefficient
      X_T = t(X)
      Wout = Yt %*% X_T %*% solve( X %*% X_T + reg*diag(1+inSize+resSize) )

      # run the trained ESN in a generative mode. no need to initialize here,
      # because x is initialized with training data and we continue from there.
      Y = matrix(0,outSize,testLen)
      u = data[trainLen+1]
      for (t in 1:testLen) {
      x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
      y = Wout %*% rbind(1,u,x)
      Y[,t] = y
      # generative mode:
      u = y
      # this would be a predictive mode:
      #u = data[trainLen+t+1]
      }

  # compute MSE for the first errorLen time steps
  errorLen = 500
  mse = ( sum( (data[(trainLen+2):(trainLen+errorLen+1)] - Y[1,1:errorLen])^2 )
/ errorLen )
  print( paste( 'Reservoir Size =',resSize))
  print( paste( 'Leakage Rate =',a))
  print( paste( 'MSE = ', mse ) )

  # plot some signals
  dev.new()
  plot( data[(trainLen+1):(trainLen+testLen+1)], type='l', col='green' )
  lines( c(Y), col='blue' )
  title(main=expression(paste('Target and generated signals ', bold(y)(italic(n)),
' starting at ', italic(n)==0 )))
  legend('bottomleft',legend=c('Target signal', 'Free-running predicted signal'),
col=c('green','blue'), lty=1, bty='n' )

  dev.new()
  matplot( t(X[(1:20),(1:200)]), type='l' )
  title(main=expression(paste('Some reservoir activations ', bold(x)(italic(n)))))

 dev.new()
 barplot( Wout )
 title(main=expression(paste('Output weights ', bold(W)^{out})))

 mseDF <- rbind(mseDF, data.frame(resSize, a, mse)) }
}
```

Comment: You are only `print` ing on the console.  I would do `resSize_lst <- list(); `a_lst <- list()` and `mse_lst <- list()` outside the loop and then append inside the loop, i.e. `resSize_lst <- c(resSize_lst, resSize)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Using the modified code in the question, before the first `for` insert this line to initialize `mseDF`:

```
mseDF <- NULL
```

and just before the second last } insert this line to append a row to it:

```
mseDF <- rbind(mseDF, data.frame(resSize, a, mse))
```

When the code finishes `mseDF` will be a data frame that looks like this:

```
mseDF
##   resSize   a          mse
## 1     100 0.3 1.652439e-02
## 2     100 0.5          Inf
## 3     100 0.7 1.237748e+05
## 4     500 0.3 2.955434e-06
## 5     500 0.5 1.083321e-05
## 6     500 0.7 1.446731e-05
## 7    1000 0.3 1.820381e-06
## 8    1000 0.5 4.680945e-06
## 9    1000 0.7 1.299191e-04
```

or if you prefer a 2d table of mse values then transform `mseDF` like this:

```
xtabs(mse ~., mseDF)
##        a
## resSize          0.3          0.5          0.7
##    100  1.652439e-02          Inf 1.237748e+05
##    500  2.955434e-06 1.083321e-05 1.446731e-05
##    1000 1.820381e-06 4.680945e-06 1.299191e-04
```

**2)**  Another approach is to create an `mseFun` function which calculates the mse for one value of each input and then apply it to each row of the grid `g` to produce a data frame result. Here we will use a simple version of `mseFun` just to illustate:

```
mseFun <- function(resSize, a) {
  a + resSize # replace this with your calculation of mse
}

g <- expand.grid(resSize = c(100, 500, 1000), a = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7)) # 9x2
transform(g, mse = mapply(mseFun, resSize, a))
```

Comment: thank you! this worked! I added your answer in the original post

Comment: if possible and if you have time, could you please explain : trainLen, testLen, initLen and errorLen? in the original code, are 2000 points being used for training, 2000 points used for testing, 100 points used for a sliding window and error is being measured on the final 500 points? thank you again

Comment: You can use dim(...) to find the dimensions of the various matrices and from that determine the sizes.